# How to retrieve the inserted value immediately at the time of insertion in DB

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, logic

My problem is when inserting values to DB after inserting i want to get the values from that table immediatly but i got exception in that.

My code is like:

```
    //insert values to DB
    button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListner()) {

     public void onclick() {
    mDbHandler.addMedicinesDetails(new MedicineList(mName, barcode_value,dosage_per_day,
                                 days, notes));

    //Retrieve value from DB

    mMedicineList= mDbHandler.getMedicineId(mName,barcode_value,dosage_per_day,days,notes);
    long medicineid = mMedicineList.get(0).getId();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+mMedicineList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

MY DB Code:

```
public void addMedicinesDetails(MedicineList medicineList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MEDICINENAME, medicineList.getMedicineName());
    values.put(BARCODE, medicineList.getBarcodeValue());
    values.put(DOSAGEPERDAY, medicineList.getDosage_per_day());
    values.put(DAY, medicineList.getDays());
    values.put(NOTES, medicineList.getNotes());

    db.insert(TABLENAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

i don't know it is good or not.

Please anybody provide a suggestion to do this...

Comment: Show code of data insert into table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***SQLite [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.***

So why not you modify your `addMedicinesDetails()` to return inserted id. Like below example

```
long newRowId = db.insert(
         FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
         FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE,
         values);
return newRowId
```

---

After viewing your modification you code should be

```
public long addMedicinesDetails(MedicineList medicineList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MEDICINENAME, medicineList.getMedicineName());
    values.put(BARCODE, medicineList.getBarcodeValue());
    values.put(DOSAGEPERDAY, medicineList.getDosage_per_day());
    values.put(DAY, medicineList.getDays());
    values.put(NOTES, medicineList.getNotes());

    long id = db.insert(TABLENAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    return id; 
}
```

Comment: i am using arraylist for insert the value to DB.

Comment: but you are inserting only one value into DB

Comment: but it inserts data more than one time.

Comment: Where you are inserting more than one time???????? I didn't see any loop inside the method? and if your are using loop then you can add these ids to list..

Comment: I only updated the code to take returned value only. Check your code... there is no any issue..

Comment: sorry it is my mistake i forget to remove this line db.insert(TABLENAME, null, values);